# Why do i get Message: Illegal offset type and what does it mean

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

When using CodeIgnator I get the followeing error when i try to use my database:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal offset type

Filename: models/flight_model.php

Line Number: 12

The code that produces this errors :

```
     $query = $this->db->query('SELECT Date, ID, Destination FROM flight');

       $flights= array();
         foreach ($query->result() as $row)
          {
                $flights[$row] = array('flight_id' => $row->ID, 'Date'=>$row->Date, 'Destination' => $row->Destination);
          }
```

I don't understand what the problem is with the code :S

All answers are appriciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error because `$row` is not a valid array key (I assume it's an object of some sorts). Array keys can only be strings or numbers.

What you can do though is make use of the row ID as the key instead:

```
$flights[$row->ID] = ...
```